# How can I store event handlers in separate document

Tags: javascript

I'm using this JavaScript code to change style sheets from [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/).

The code looks like this:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);
```

Now, on the site it is suggested to add this code in the HTML where you want the link: 
    change style to default 
I tried using this and it works fine.

But I'd like to have my event handlers in a separate document so I use this instead:

```
<head>

<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme1.css" title="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme2.css" title="theme2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme3.css" title="theme3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body

<ul id="dropdown">
<li> Choose theme
    <ul> 
        <li id="stylesheet1" > <a href="#"> Default </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet2" > <a href="#"> Theme 1 </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet3" > <a href="#"> Theme 2 </a></li>
        <li id="stylesheet4" > <a href="#"> Theme 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
 </li> 

</body>
```

With this added in my javascript.js file:

```
function initate()
{
var style1 = document.getElementById("stylesheet1");
var style2 = document.getElementById("stylesheet2");
var style3 = document.getElementById("stylesheet3");
var style4 = document.getElementById("stylesheet4");

style1.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("default.css"); 
    return false;
    };
style2.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme1.css"); 
    return false;
    };
style3.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme2.css"); 
    return false
    };
style4.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme3.css"); 
    return false
    };          
}

window.onload = initate;
```

But for some reason this doesn't work and I can't figure out why.  The way it is now, both my `default.css` and `theme1.css` are loaded and when I press any button in the list `theme1.css` is disabled and nothing else happens when I press any of the other buttons.

Comment: That article you're working from is **ancient** in web-software terms.

Comment: In which file is your functions like `setActiveStyleSheet` defined? Is it in the HTML file or a separate `.js` file?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Pointy Do you have a better solution to do what this script is suppose to do?

Comment: @ATOzTOA All my javascripts are in my javascript file. The way it is now, both my default.css and theme1.css is loaded and when I press any button in the list theme1.css is disabled and nothing else happens when I press any of the other buttons.  
Updated the question with this information as well ass how I've written my links to the css files.

Comment: @Benji well swapping out complete stylesheets seems like a fairly coarse-grained way of doing things. Personally I'd prefer to use something like a class name on the `<body>` or `<html>` tag to drive different rules for different themes.

Comment: @Pointy I would love if you could specify how I can do that since my knowledge in javascripting is pretty basic and I don't really know how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Benji it's just a CSS thing: you write rules with a class prefixing the selector, and so when you change the class on the overall container the set of rules in effect will change.  Like, `.style1 .whatever` to `.style2 .whatever`.

Comment: @Pointy I'm still not sure what you mean by this :(

Comment: @ATOzTOA Do you have any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `setActiveStyleSheet` takes the `title` as argument.

Here is the working code:

**HTML**

```
<head>

<link href="default.css" title="default" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme1.css" title="theme1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme2.css" title="theme2" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="theme3.css" title="theme3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

**Javascript**

```
style1.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("default"); 
    return false;
    };
style2.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme1"); 
    return false;
    };
style3.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme2"); 
    return false
    };
style4.onclick = function () { 
    setActiveStyleSheet("theme3"); 
    return false
    };          
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Been pulling my hair trying to figure out was was wrong and I was pretty darn sure it was something very small.. I just have one small followup question, how do I make the cookies stay for at least 7 days?

Comment: Cookie has a `expires` attribute, just set it.

Comment: How do I do that? My javascript knowledge is very basic and I don't understand most of the scripts here :(

Comment: Aren't you using `function createCookie(name,value,days) {` to set the cookie? Just use the last argument.

Comment: I don't know how to implement that function into my code at all.. Changing the themes worked fine but it didn't save the theme so I just assumed that the cookie was deleted right away. But I don't know how to put it in the code.

Comment: Just call this from your code `createCookie("myCookieName", "mycookievalue, 7);`